# Найти ошибку в скрипте

Tags: javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Ступеньки </title>
<body bgcolor="yellow">
<p><H2>Это программа позволяет следить за координатами объекта, который поднимается и спускается по ступенькам
<br>Высота каждой ступеньки равна фиксированной единице и равна 1<br>Шаг равен 3 </H2></p>
<script type="text/javascript">
alert("добро пожаловать")
function f(obj)
{

var h=5*Math.random()+5
obj.s1.value=Math.round(h)
arrx=new Array()
arry=new Array()
x=0;x2=0
for(i=0;i<=h;i++){
 x=x+x2

y=i
arrx.push(x)
arry.push(y)
x2=Math.round(2*Math.random()+1)

}
obj.s3.value=arrx
obj.s4.value=arry

} 
function f1(obj){
obj.s3.value=arrx.reverse(x)
obj.s4.value=arry.reverse(y)
}

</script>
<form name="myform">
 количество ступенек<input type="text" name="s1" size=10  ><hr>

координаты X<input type="text" name="s3" size=60  ><hr>
координаты Y<input type="text" name="s4" size=60  ><hr>

<input type=button name="c"value=" поднимаемся" 
onclick="f(myform)">
<input type=button name="w"value=" спускаемся" 
onclick="f1(myform)">

<input type="reset"value="cброс">

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Почему то координата по y не всегда равна количеству ступенек в чем ошибка?

Answer (score 3):

Это из-за того, что вы выводите округленное количество ступенек, а сравниваете в цикле с неокругленным.

```
var h=5*Math.random()+5
obj.s1.value=Math.round(h)
//...
for(i=0;i<=h;i++){
```

Замените первые две строки на

```
var h=Math.round(5*Math.random()+5)
obj.s1.value=h
```

И еще, наверное, в цикле нужно сравнение *строго меньше* (<) вместо *меньше или равно* (<=). То есть так:

```
for(i=0;i<h;i++){
```

Хотя это от постановки задачи зависит.

Comment: спасибо помогло!

Comment: Пожалуйста. Успехов!